# URL for password change link in Auth0 VueJS app

Tags: auth0, auth0-js

I have a VueJS app that uses Auth0. (It uses `@auth0/auth0-vue` but I don't think that's actually relevant.)

I'd like to add a link to a page where the user can change their password. I believe that should be possible within the Universal Login, but I can't figure out what the URL should be.

What is the URL for this?